# TiledMap resizing and aspect ratio with LibGDX

Tags: java, 2d, graphics, libgdx

I'm making a game and I don't know how to resize my TiledMap when the window is bigger but keeping its squared shape.

Here is a screen:

[image]

When I change window size, here's what happens:
[image]

[image]

I want to see all the map with all window sizes.

Here's my GameScreen file

http://pastebin.com/rgKgHskN

Thank you for your help and I'm sorry for those big screenshots and for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LibGDX 1.0 provides what you need : Viewports.

The idea is to work with a known virtual screen size and then have it resized to fit your real screen.

I recommend you to give a look at this tutorial that explains how to handle game screen resizing with Viewports : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: This is almost it but the top half part of the map won't render.